# Documenting prerelease features or concepts

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-editor

Should we be documenting proposal/in-development features or concepts? There is a whole section dedicated to C# 7.0 which isn't out yet. My gut says no since it's so apt to changing.

I tried to add a version for it with in-development and the regex cancelled that out.

Comment: Given how much the likes of .NET core has changed, I'd certainly be leaning towards the "no" side of things.

Comment: I would also hang towards 'no': it is not useful nor easy for users when they have a question and find documentation on alphas/betas that doesn't apply for the official released version.

Comment: I would tend to yes. But with proper versioning (maybe including date) and a prerelease-tag. So after the stable version is out it can easily filtered out (automatically?). I would find it helpful when testing preview versions of api's. However there is nothing more frustrating than finding examples that uses no longer existing methods.